# d3.js: Update multiple pie charts

Tags: d3.js

This question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911019/d3-multiple-pie-chart-updates) but I don't think the given solution is the cleanest way to do it so I'm hoping someone may have figured it out since then.

I am generating multiple pie charts using d3.js and am dynamically updating them through SQL queries. This is my update function:

```
function updateCharts()
{
    var updatedDataSet = getDataSet();

    // Create a pie layout and bind the new data to it
    var layout = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d, i) { return d[i].count; })
        .sort(null);

    // Select the pie chart
    var pieChartSVG = d3.selectAll("#pie");

    // Select each slice of the pie chart
    var arcsUpdate = pieChartSVG.selectAll("g.slice")
        .data(layout([updatedDataSet]))
        .enter();

    // Apply transitions to the pie chart to reflect the new dataset
    arcsUpdate.select("path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", arc)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", arcTween);
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I take the `.enter()` out of `arcsUpdate` then it works but applies the same changes(data and tweens) to each chart. I could get around this by doing a `foreach()` on the elements returned from `pieChartSVG` but I can't think of a way of doing that other than the one described in the other question.

I have had to use the solution from the other question as I have to move forward but it's not a "clean" solution so I'd love to know if anybody is aware of a better way to handle it.

Comment: If getDataSet() is returning updated data, why are you using the enter selection? In the solution to the question you linked to, there is no call to enter, so the arcs in the update selection are being updated, as they should be. I have found the reusable chart pattern helpful in cases like this ( http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/ ), binding an update handler to your charts, and dispatching a listener to an object bound to your data. If you have a fiddle containing all of your code that would be helpful.

Comment: We don't know how exactly your code works but here is a great example of updating multiple charts with the help of d3.dispatch, maybe it will help you - [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848)

Answer (score 1):

I thought you need take the `.enter()` out of `arcsUpdate` just like

```
var arcsUpdate = pieChartSVG.selectAll("path")
    .data(layout([updatedDataSet]));

// Apply transitions to the pie chart to reflect the new dataset
arcsUpdate.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("d", arc)
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween);
```

This is the correct way.
And if it applies the same changes(data and tweens) to each chart. Please check out they are binding same `updateDataSet` or not.